# What is the first file that is read on solidus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solidus

Might sound like a easy question but can't find an answer... **What is the first file that the interpreter reads when launching Solidus?** I know it's a rails app but the code seemed to have been extensively modified.

Comment: Not sure, why is this information needed? In which environment?

Comment: Well rails is a ruby script. Would be useful to follow the script from the start.

Answer (score 0):

A Solidus app is just a Rails app, you can follow the instructions in the Rails Guides: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html